# What version of RDP is used in Windows 8?

Tags: linux, remote-desktop, windows-8, rdp, screensharing

I've tried to connect to Windows 8 Developer Preview via rdesktop 1.6 and freerdp 0.8.2 from linux and there was no success.

I've get:

> ui_unimpl: NOT IMPLEMENTED: Unknown Capability Set 0x1E ui_unimpl: NOT
>   IMPLEMENTED: Bpp 254

Although I could set a connection from Windows 7. What is the version of RDP on Windows 8? Is there any rdp client on linux that supports such version?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RDP underwent significant work in Windows 8 and likely does not yet have any support from non-Microsoft maintained clients. Remoting from Windows 7 should work properly. Some capabilities that were added in Windows 7 may now be taken advantage of which is why Windows 7 to Windows 8 may work while Linux to Windows 8 may not. That is to say, Windows 7's RDP client already supported the new capabilities.

Comment: Could you back up this claim with some public information? I realise from your page that you work at MS and can't discuss everything, but I'd like to see more data if available.

Comment: To be honest, I'm unsure of whether I can discuss the nature of the improvements yet. I will say that something you can try is watching video over RDP from one Windows 8 computer to another Windows 8 computer. Additionally you can try opening the "Fish Tank" demo on a remote Windows 8 machine from a local Windows 8 client.

Answer (score 2):

Below change work around windows8 display problem. Somehow the bpp is zero when connecting windows8.

Tested with "xfreerdp --no-nla "

```
diff --git a/client/X11/xf_graphics.c b/client/X11/xf_graphics.c
index afbf773..beb3afe 100644
--- a/client/X11/xf_graphics.c
+++ b/client/X11/xf_graphics.c
@@ -109,6 +109,7 @@ void xf_Bitmap_Decompress(rdpContext* context, rdpBitmap* bitmap,
 {
    uint16 size;

+   if (!bpp) bpp = 16;
    size = width * height * (bpp + 7) / 8;

    if (bitmap->data == NULL)
```

Answer (score 1):

For those stumbling onto this question:

Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 support RDPv8: ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Remote_Desktop_Protocol#Version_8.0))

Remmina ([remmina@sourceforge](http://remmina.sourceforge.net/)), implementing FreeRDP ([FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/)), is able to connect to Windows 8/Windows Server 2012 -- I'm currently using Remmina to successfully connect to a WS2012 machine.

Answer (score 0):

FreeRdp is aiming to support win8

when I tried it logged it but fails to display properly

Bitmap Decompression Failed

Until release 1.0 gets out you can try it :

https://github.com/FreeRDP/FreeRDP/wiki/Compilation

I am investigating

http://rzr.online.fr/q/rdp

Answer (score 0):

Maybe Remmina or Freerdp or Rdesktop connect to Windows Server 2012 but we have to be sure that is using the RDPv8 and it is not running on RDPv7 in a sort of compatibility mode.

Let me tell you, the performance gain of using RDPv8 is gigantic. See this video about remoting desktop is very interesting:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IJVu27EGijg

those guys in the video have done a excellent job evaluating Windows remote protocols.